# Unable to understand the concept of a 1-bit PRF

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

In his lecture on building Block Ciphers from PRGS, Dan Boneh says this

> - Let’s start by finding out if we can build PRF from a PRG?
> - Let $G:\ K \to K^2$ be a secure PRG
> - Define 1-bit PRF $F:\ K \times \{0,1\} \to K$ as $F(k, x\in\{0,1\}) = G(k)[x]$
>   $\quad F$: if $0$ choose $G(k)[0]$, if $1$, choose $G(k)[1]$

I am unable to understand what is a 1-bit PRF. A PRG takes only the seed as input. So what is the $\{0,1\}$ in $F:\ K \times \{0,1\} \to K$ - considering that $K$ is the key/seed of the PRG.

And what does $G(k)[x]$ in $F(k, x\in\{0,1\}) = G(k)[x]$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is a 1-bit PRF?

That would usually be a PRF with a 1-bit output, but the rest of the text clarifies it is meant a 1-bit *input*.

> what is the $\{0,1\}$ in $F:\ K \times \{0,1\} \to K$ ?

It is the set with two elements $0$ and $1$. This also is the set of the possible values of the second/right/normal/non-key component of the input of the PRF $F$.

Note: a [Pseudo Random Function Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) (confusingly abbreviated PRF just like a Pseudo Random Function) has two inputs (equivalently: an input consisting of an [ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair)). The first (the left component of the pair) is the key, and the second (the right one) is the normal/non-key input (which is the single input of any particular member of the Pseudo Random Function Family). The member of the Pseudo Random Function Family corresponding to key $k$ is often noted $F_k$. By that notation $F_k(x)=F(k,x)=F((k,x))$. Here, $F_k:\ \{0,1\}\to K$ (that's a particular Pseudo Random Function for a certain key $k$), since $F:\ K \times \{0,1\} \to K$ (that's the whole Pseudo Random Function Family).

> what does $G(k)[x]$ in $F(k, x\in\{0,1\}) = G(k)[x]$ mean?

The PRG $G$ takes an input $k$ and produces an output $G(k)$ consisting of two parts of the same width as $k$, as apparent in $G:\ K \to K^2$. This is the same as  $G:\ K \to K\times K$. That is, the output of $G$ is an [ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) of bitstrings, assimilated to a bitstring twice as wide as $k$, that we split in two parts as wide as $k$, each from the same set $K$ as $k$ is from.

$G(k)[x]$ is the first or the second component/part of the output of $G(k)$, according to $x$ being $0$ or $1$. It's also the output of $F$ for input $(k,x)$ where $k$ is the PRF's key, and $x$ is the PRF's second/right/normal/non-key input, which is a single bit.

> What exactly is $x$?

It's a bit. It's not an input of the PRG $G$. It selects among the two halves of the output of the PRG $G$ for input $k$, that is $G(k)$. We can think of $[x]$ as we'd do for `[x]` in a computer language with indexes.

Comment: What exactly is `x`? A PRG takes only 1 input - the seed - here we see 2 inputs `k` & `x`. What is the 2nd input?

Comment: What exactly is meant by "first or the second component/part of the output of G(k)" - what exactly is meant by "component" of the output?

Comment: @user: please re-read the part of the (edited) answer where I explain the notation means $G:\ K \to K\times K$, that is the output of $G$ is an ordered pair $(u,v)$ of two bitstrings of the same width as $k$. The first or second components of the output of $G$ are $u$ or $v$. The notation $[x]$ selects the first (when $x=0$) or the second (when $x=1$).

Comment: you say `that is the set of the possible values of the second/right/normal/non-key component of the input` - I am unable to understand why there is a 2nd or non-key component of the input - why would a PRG take input other than a key?

Comment: `the output of G is an ordered pair (u,v) of two bitstrings of the same width as k.` - ok - got this part' - i assume this means that the size of the output is twice the size of the input.

Comment: @user93353: I'm stating _"that is the set of the possible values of the second/right/normal/non-key component of the input **of the PRF $F$**"_. $x$ is not an input of $G$. Indeed $G$ has a single input, noted $k$. $x$ enters $F$. :-( I really don't understand what is meant by `second/right/normal/non-key component of the input `

Comment: Also Boneh says "if input is 0, then output G(k)[0] & if input is 1, then output G(k)[1]` - This is also stumps me - how can you output just half the output? Irrespective of what is the input, won't a function output the whole output & not just either the left or right half of it? i.e. irrespective of whether input is 0 or 1, won't the whole of G(k) be output not just G(k)[0] or just G(k)[1]?

Comment: I think i finally got everything. Thank you for your help.